# sudo without changing $USER or whoami

Tags: linux, sudo

`sudo whoami` returns root.

How do you change the argument so that you run `whoami` with elevated privileges, without changing the user? (What is expected to print is the current user, not root, but with elevated privilages.)

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? If you want to print the user who invoked `sudo`, retrieve `$SUDO_USER`. Proof of concept: `sudo sh -c 'echo "$SUDO_USER"'`. You can build a wrapper for `whoami` that uses the variable if set.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not understand what you are trying to achieve or what the actual problem is, however this will work.

```
sudo -u $USER whoami
```

Please read [sudo documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), when you run sudo without any argument username, it runs as root user, so your current user is root.

Above will not work when you run after sudo su, since $USER will return root.
Above will also not work in case of a script being run as root.

Comment: This won't provide elevated privileges though - it'll provide the privileges of the specified `$USER`.